# Record and Play using AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I am creating an app in which user can record and play the recorded file.
I am able to record and play as well, but the problem I am facing is that while playing(listening) the recording, if user presses the record button it will start recording and pressing on the stop resumes the previous recording where it was left.

What I want is when user is listening to the recording and in the mean while he presses the record button, then the last recording (which he was playing) should get destroyed.

In short,I do not want to resume the last recording, I want to play the recent recording.

Here is my code for recording and playback.

```
   -(void)showStopbutton
    {
        if (flag_for_mic_button == 0)
        {
            // All in vain the following condition not making any effect palyer is resuming back
            if ([audioPlayer isPlaying])
            {
                [audioPlayer stop];
                audioPlayer = nil;
                audioPlayer = NO;
            }
            //

            [btn_Mic setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stop.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            lbl_Press.hidden = TRUE;
            lbl_updateTime.hidden = FALSE;
            [self startRecording];
            flag_for_mic_button = 1;
        }
        else if (flag_for_mic_button ==1)
        {
            [self stopRecording];

            // All in vain the following condition not making any effect palyer is resuming back

            if ([audioPlayer isPlaying])
            {
                audioPlayer = NO;
                [audioPlayer stop];
                audioPlayer = nil;
            }

            //

            [btn_Mic setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            lbl_Press.hidden = FALSE;
            lbl_updateTime.hidden = TRUE;
            flag_for_mic_button = 0;
        }
    }

-(void)startRecording
{
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *err = nil;
    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
    err = nil;
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }
    recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:44100.0f] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    caldate =[now description];
    recorderFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@ MyRecording.caf",DOCUMENTS_FOLDER,caldate];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];
    err=nil;
    audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
    [audioRecorder setDelegate:self];
    [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
    audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

    [audioRecorder record];

    [self setTimer];
    [self hidePlaybackView];
}

-(void)stopRecording
{
    [audioRecorder stop];
    [start_Timer invalidate];
    [self showPlaybackView];

}

-(void)playSound
{
//    [self playBackTimer];

    if (!recorderFilePath)
    {
        recorderFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@ MyRecording.caf",DOCUMENTS_FOLDER,caldate];
    }

    if(soundID)
    {
        AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
    }


    //Get a URL for the sound file
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath isDirectory:NO];

    //Use audio sevices to create the sound
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain(filePath), &soundID);

    //Use audio services to play the sound
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:filePath error:nil];

    [audioPlayer play];

    audioPlayer.delegate = self;

}
```

**EDIT:**

```
-(void)showPlaybackView
{
    view_playback = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 600, 320, 80)];
    view_playback.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view_playback];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    view_playback.frame = CGRectMake(0, 325, 320, 55);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    btn_Playback = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn_Playback setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn_Playback.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 35, 35);
    [view_playback addSubview:btn_Playback];
    [btn_Playback addTarget:self action:@selector(playSound) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    btn_done = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn_done setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn_done.frame = CGRectMake(265, 15, 45, 30);
    btn_done.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    [view_playback addSubview:btn_done];

    [view_playback addSubview:playback_slider];


    [btn_done addTarget:self action:@selector(Done) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: In the method `-(void)stopRecording` you are stopping the recording not deleting the existing recording . Y ?

Comment: if i delete that recording then how would listen the recorded file

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have a button to play the recorded file, but at the same time I am giving the provision the record a new file and after recording pressing on play button will play the recent recording.

and moreover using `[audioPlayer stop]` making no effect it is only pausing the currently playing file.

Comment: After stopping the `audioPlayer`, try releasing the same & allocate a new instance each time.This way it restart & not resume.

Comment: releasing audioPlayer causing bad access in `-(void)playSound` on `NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath isDirectory:NO];` on this line.

Comment: Where are you calling this `playSound` method. i can't see the call in your code

Comment: Please see the edit part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped the Audio Player and do not let it resume back by using the following code.

```
if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    audioPlayer.currentTime=0;
}
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this approach :**

```
  -(void)showStopbutton
{
        if (![audioPlayer isPlaying])
        {
            [audioPlayer start];
           // other stuff
        }

        if ([audioPlayer isPlaying])
        {
            [audioPlayer stop];
            // Delete the previous recording in the delegate method of audio player       
        }

}
```